# CSS Sprite Sheet Animation not Working (Scrolling Side-to-Side)

Tags: css, css-sprites

I using CSS animation to animate a character. I've completed one animation successfully but when I try other animations I get strange affects, like either scrolling side ways or up. I'm using Texture Packer to create the sprite sheet.

[image: results]

Through my research I've tried different approaches:

- Keeping the sprites on one row. I've tried various sprite sheets,
  some with one row and others that contain multiple sprite movements
  that are 4 x8.
- Multiple character movements on one sprite sheet (idle, run, walk,
  etc.).
- Keeping only one character movement sprite sheet (only idle).

These are just some of things I've tried with no success. 
I'm not sure if I just don't fundamentally understand how sprite sheets work in CSS or if I'm making a simple mistake. Anyone have any thought on how get my animations to work?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<span class="jellyYellow0001 sprite"></span>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -127px; } /*I've played with this value*/
}


.sprite {

    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url(jellyYellow.png);
    width: 130px;
    height: 110px;
    animation: play 1s steps(8) infinite;

}

.jellyYellow0001 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -1px -1px}
.jellyYellow0002 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -127px -1px}
.jellyYellow0003 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -253px -1px}
.jellyYellow0004 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -379px -1px}
.jellyYellow0005 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -505px -1px}
.jellyYellow0006 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -631px -1px}
.jellyYellow0007 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -757px -1px}
.jellyYellow0008 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -883px -1px}
.jellyYellow0009 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -1009px -1px}
.jellyYellow0010 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -1135px -1px}
```

Here is one version of the sprite sheet.
[image: Sprite sheet 1]

Here is another sprite sheet I've tried.
[image: Sprite sheet 2]

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -127px; } /*I've played with this value*/
}


.sprite {
 display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Xxv.png);
    width: 130px;
    height: 110px;
    animation: play 1s steps(8) infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;

}

.jellyYellow0001 {width:124px; height:108px; background-position: -1px -1px}
```

```html
<span class="jellyYellow0001 sprite"></span>
```

in the sprite  selector U need to add animation-iteration-count: 1;

Comment: with 'animation-iteration-count: 1' it continues to scroll right to left. That's not what I'm looking for. This animation is an idle animation where the character breathes.